# How to use Java Stream API to iterate through a HashMap with custom object

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a hashmap with key as object below

I want to be able to iterates through the hashmap , and retrieves values only for keys matching name and second value in symbol i.e lmn , hij

Example: if input is **pqr** and **hij** , result should return 500. I want to be able to do this using Java stream API

```
class Product {
   String name;
   String symbol;
}
```

Example values

```
    KEY.               VALUE
name symbol
abc  12|lmn|standard   1000
pqr  14|hij|local      500
```

Comment: If you want to look up a particular key in a hashmap, you don't need to iterate through the hashmap. You just look up that particular key. That's what hashmaps are for. Where is your hashmap and what difficulty are you having?

Comment: Its not a particular key, its name and part of symbol that i have to match

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code definition of your `HashMap` - is it `Map<Product, Integer>`?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```java
map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().name.equals(nameMatch))
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().symbol.contains("|" + keyMatch + "|"))
    .map(e -> e.getValue()).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

It may be better to just create a predicate that checks the product:

```java
Predicate<Product> matcher = matcher(nameMatch, symbolMatch);
Integer result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> matcher.test(e.getKey()))
    .map(e -> e.getValue()).findFirst().orElse(null);

...

private static Predicate<Product> matcher(String name, String symbolPart) {
    String symbolMatch = "|" + symbolPart + "|";
    return product -> product.name.equals(name) &&
        product.symbol.contains(symbolMatch);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But i want to also search name field. And how to collect it?

Comment: Edited - see above. If it doesn't work for you, can you explain if the result is wrong, or if it throws an exception, thanks